# Kolmogorov's forward equation, Tensor, not sure of composition/multiplication rules

Tags: markov-chains, tensor-products

I am preparing for an MLC certification, and have gone far afield into my own little world.

We are introduced to Kolmogorov's forward equation, which essentially has the form

$$P'=PM.$$

In my case, $P$ is a matrix of transition probabilities, and $M$ is a matrix of transition intensities. For one application, we have two lives and two states for each, and mnemonically, the states can be associated as binary, 0=00, both alive, 1=01, wife dead, 2=10, husband dead, and 3=11, both dead. In most of the relevant material, we assume the distributions are independent. At this point, I wondered if I could simplify the matrix somehow, and I thought it looked a lot like a tensor product, and it seems to work. So I write

$$P=P_x\otimes P_y.$$

In other words, it seems okay to write

$$
P_x\otimes P_y   = 
\begin{pmatrix}
p_x & q_x \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{pmatrix}
p_y & q_y \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
p_xp_y & p_xq_y & q_xp_y & q_xq_y \\ 
0 & p_x & 0 & q_x \\
0&0&p_y&q_y\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

But then I try to do the same for the mortality matrix, I write

$$
M_m\otimes M_f   = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-\mu_m & \mu_m \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{pmatrix}
-\mu_f & \mu_f \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\overset?\ne
\begin{pmatrix}
-\mu_f - \mu_m- \mu_{mf} & \mu_f  & \mu_m  & \mu_{mf}\\
0  & -\mu_m   & 0    & \mu_m\\
0  & 0    & -\mu_f    & \mu_f\\
0  & 0     & 0     & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is there a rule I don't know about? Something to do with derivatives?

---

EDIT: I did notice a trick that seems to work, If I replace the diagonal with 1s, then I get a better match, that is

$$
M_m\otimes M_f    
\overset?\ne\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \mu_m \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \mu_f \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\overset?=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \mu_f  & \mu_m  & \mu_{mf}\\
0  & 1   & 0    & \mu_m\\
0  & 0    & 1    & \mu_f\\
0  & 0     & 0     & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Why does this work out the way it does?

---

2nd EDIT:

If I write $M$ as a sum of a nilpotent matrix and a diagonal one, ie $M=N+D$, we note it is easy to recover $D$, so we discard it.

And above, we note we have the form

$$\big((I+N_x)\otimes(I+N_y)\big)-I=N.$$

So we can easily construct $M$ from $M_x$ and $M_y$. But I've no idea why this works.

Comment: Is $\mu_{mf}=\mu_m \mu_f$? If not, it is an undefined parameter.

Comment: I assume so yes. It is often zero, perhaps a negligible contribution, but there is something called common shock, but I'm not worried about it, so we can assume $\mu_m\mu_f=0=\mu_{mf}$ if it helps.

Comment: That is, I made up the symbol $\mu_{mf}=\mu_m\mu_f$. In a text I have, that doesn't really try to look at things in quite this way, it's written $\mu_{x+t}^{03}$. It's a "common shock" term that is usually not considered. The book is Actuarial Mathematics for Life Contingent Risks by Dickson, Hardy and Waters. They never write a matrix, but I thought it would be helpful to have this way of going at things, especially since other parts of the syllabus do include matrices. They write the Kolmogorov equation in index notation.

Comment: That's a little beyond me, but I've added an answer that I *hope* may resolve some of your difficulties.

Comment: In essence, the common shock is likely an artificial step added in for the 4 states, and does not come from the perspective of two lives of two states. There, it would be two steps from none dead to both dead, and transition intensities across two or more steps are assumed zero. And thank you greatly for your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transition matrices for paired, independent continuous time Markov chains are, as you expect given by the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)  $e^{tM_m}\otimes e^{t M_f}$. Differentiating and setting $t=0$ we see that the paired process has generator $M_m\oplus M_f:=(M_m\otimes I)+(I\otimes M_f)$, the *Kronecker sum*. That is, $$e^{t(M_m\oplus M_f)}=e^{tM_m}\otimes e^{t M_f}\neq e^{t(M_m\otimes M_f)}.$$

For the matrices you give, the Kronecker sum  works out to $$\pmatrix{-\mu_m-\mu_f&\mu_f&\mu_m&0\cr0&-\mu_m&0&\mu_m\cr0&0&-\mu_f&\mu_f\cr0&0&0&0}.$$

Comment: Glad to be of help.